# Is there a way to avoid/short cut when using Application.someBuilt-InFunction in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code in which I use vba's built-in functions but it gets confusing to read since I have a lot of `Application.mmult()` and `Application.minverse`

This is my code:

```
Function MReg (Rango as Range) as variant
 MReg=application.mmult(application.minverse(application.mmult(Rango,application.transpose(Rango))),application.transpose(Rango))

End function
```

Is there a way to set VBA so that `Application.` is not nessesary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have two good answers, nevertheless this is something more elegant:

Create functions that will do what you need but in an structured way.

```
Public Function MULT(M1 As Range, M2 As Range) As Variant
 MULT = Application.MMult(M1, M2)
End Function

Public Function TRANSPOSE(M1 As Range) As Variant
 TRANSPOSE = Application.TRANSPOSE(M1)
End Function

Public Function INVERSE(M1 As Range) As Variant
INVERSE = Application.MInverse(M1)
End Function
```

Then you can use these functions into you "Main" function without problem and I'll look much better:

```
Function MREG(X As Range, Y As Range) As Variant
 MREG = MULT(MULT(INVERSE(MULT(X, TRANSPOSE(X))), TRANSPOSE(X)), Y)
End Function
```

I assumed you wanted to create a function to run a multiple regression, that's why i modified a little bit your code.

Answer (score 2):

This will do it for you:

```
Function MReg (Rango as Range) as variant
   With Application
     MReg= .mmult(.minverse(.mmult(Rango,.transpose(Rango))),.transpose(Rango))
   End With
End function
```

Comment: You might also use extra lines to hep with readability. I use this frequently.

For instance add a line continuation after .Mmult( and newline, after .MInvers( and newline and so on.

Can't seem to add code to comments otherwise I would give the example.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, and I know what line continuation is, so no need for an example. That is stylistic preference, and I prefer my code to look like the above.

Answer (score 2):

use `With -End With` block

```
Function MReg(Rango As Range) As Variant
    With Application
        MReg = .MMult(.MInverse(.MMult(Rango, .Transpose(Rango))), .Transpose(Rango))
    End With
End Function
```